# Is it possible to connect through C# to different oracle database versions?

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I need to develop a C# application that reads data from database A (oracle versione 10) and writes to database B (oracle version 19).

So both oracle client 10 and oracle client 19 must be installed on the server.

Is it possibile to perform such installation? And how do I specify that one connection string must use the first oracle client and the other must use the second?

Comment: You don't need different versions of Oracle client to connect to databases of different versions. You can use Managed ODP.NET (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) and create 2 different instances of OracleConnection to connect to both databases. You can install 19.6 version of the library - it will be able to connect both to Oracle 10g and 19c.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I need to use a third party library for oracle connection and that library relies on the Oracle Client installation.

Comment: As far as I remember the ODP. Net managed driver can connect only to database 11.1 or newer, check documentation.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, you are right. Current version of ODP.NET managed driver supports only access to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 or later. 12.x versions support access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later

Comment: @Marchinka is it well-known third party library or is it some in-house third party?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Version 10.1 or 10. 2? Check https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=552435627823737&id=207303.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=q2a2ahgzg_53 if you have 10.1 then it looks bad because no driver can connect to 19 and 10.1.If you have 10.2 then Oracle Client 11 can connect to either versions.

It is possible go install more than one Oracle Client but I don't think you can use several versions weithin one process because it relies in PATH which you cannot chance within a process.